# CLion Arduino undefined reference

Tags: arduino, clion

I have tried most of the suggestion regarding this issue to no avail.

I have created an Arduino project in CLion(version 2017.3.2) with Arduino plugin (version 1.2.3).  I kept getting "undefined reference" during build.

My main Sample.ino file is:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "Hello.h"

void setup() {
}

void loop() {
    Hello::world();
}
```

and the Hello.h is simply:

```
#ifndef SAMPLE_HELLO_H
#define SAMPLE_HELLO_H


struct Hello {
    static void world();
};


#endif //SAMPLE_HELLO_H
```

the Hello.cpp is
    #include "Hello.h"

```
void Hello::world() {
}
```

and the CMakeLists.txt is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/ArduinoToolchain.cmake)
set(PROJECT_NAME Sample)
project(${PROJECT_NAME})

set(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_SKETCH src/Sample.ino)

#include_directories(include)
include_directories(src)

#### Uncomment below additional settings as needed.
set(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_BOARD mega)
set(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_PORT /dev/ttyACM0)
set(mega.build.mcu atmega2560)
# set(mega.upload.protocol wiring)
set(mega.upload.speed 115200)

generate_arduino_firmware(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME})
```

All source files are under the folder src/,

Any suggestion to what have I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had that problem too. 
Adding this to the CMakeLists made it work:

```
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
file(GLOB SRC_FILES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp)
file(GLOB HDR_FILES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.h)

set(PROJ_SRC ${SRC_FILES})
set(PROJ_HDR ${HDR_FILES})

generate_arduino_firmware(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
    SRCS ${PROJ_SRC}
    HDRS ${PROJ_HDR}
    )
```

I'm not sure if that's the best solution but it worked in my case.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and spent several hours to find a solution.
Arduino plugin uses [arduino-cmake](https://github.com/queezythegreat/arduino-cmake) to build project. According to its documentation, to use `generate_arduino_firmware` command you should specify `SKETCH` or `SRCS` option.

If I define `SKETCH` option , I has no success to link additional files (hello.cpp).
So I try to use `SRCS`. Seems that if I define `SKETCH` and `SRCS` simultaneously, `SRCS` is be ignored. Another problem is when I specify `src/sample.ino` in `SRCS` option I have the same error.
So I do the following to compile the project successfully:

1. Renamed `src/sample.ino` into `src/sample.cpp`.
2. Commented out `SKETCH` and add `SRCS` option to list all source files:

```
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_SRCS src/sample.cpp src/hello.cpp)
```

Full CMakeList.txt is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/ArduinoToolchain.cmake)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(PROJECT_NAME Sample)
project(${PROJECT_NAME})

set(${PROJECT_NAME}_BOARD uno)
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_SRCS src/sample.cpp src/hello.cpp)
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_PROGRAMMER arduinoasisp)
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_PORT COM17)
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_AFLAGS -v)

generate_arduino_firmware(${PROJECT_NAME})
```

Answer (score 3):

The Arduino support plugin uses arduino-cmake which has a bug causing your `SRCS` and `HDRS` to be erased when compiling a sketch.

You can read my bug report and proposed fix [here](https://github.com/francoiscampbell/arduino-cmake/pull/10/files). Basically you want to modify `cmake/Platform/Arduino.cmake`

1. Change line 1808 to avoid overwriting your sources

<s>`set(ALL_SRCS ${SKETCH_SOURCES})`</s>

`set(ALL_SRCS ${ALL_SRCS} ${SKETCH_SOURCES})`

2. Change line 1821 to recompile when a source changes

<s>`DEPENDS ${MAIN_SKETCH} ${SKETCH_SOURCES}`</s>

`DEPENDS ${MAIN_SKETCH} ${ALL_SRCS}`

Comment: Thanks, you're a life saver. This should be top voted and your PR should be merged.